# Can Prometheus send its data to an external URL?

Tags: prometheus

I'm working with Prometheus and I need to export data extracted from Prometheus server to an external URL (An expresse JS server hosted by me) every time the Prometheus gets data periodically.

I can send a GET request to Prometheus server from an external server and receive data. But what I need is to **send a POST request to an external URL from Prometheus server** every time Prometheus updates.

Is it possible?

Comment: look at the documentation of the push gateway: https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway/blob/master/README.md
there is an example using CURL which should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Using the Alert Manager I can send the alerts generated to a custom URL using POST request. I just have to configure the files.
Refer [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want [remote write](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write), which will post data as it gets it in a compressed proto format over HTTP.

Comment: Do you know how to send the recorded data to a remote server using remote-write? I just added  ` remote_write: - url: "http://localhost:3000/test" ` to the `prometheus.yml`  file. Now it sends POST requests to the URL but the request body is still empty. I need to send the records with the POST request. Do you have any idea about how to do it??